# Do reverse bear traps kill survivors past the exit gate if it has not been activated?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

When a bear trap is active and you try to leave it kills you but does it still kill you if it's not active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Once the exit gates are powered, the only thing putting a trap on someone does is give you points.

This was a change implemented alongside the Endgame Collapse; prior to Endgame Collapse being added, traps would automatically activate if they were put on after the gates were powered.

Comment: Side note: This means you should probably use them as soon as you can.  At the very least, they cost the survivors time that they could otherwise spend doing generators.